# How to get bash for Windows 10 (announced in build 2016)?

Tags: bash, windows-10

When will it get released ? and How to get/install bash for Windows 10 (announced in build 2016)?

Answer (score 1):

The bash comes in a newer Insider Build, as said [in the end of the video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P488)

[image]

So yo have to wait a bit. MS added all new things in the 143xx Builds, not in 14295. But MS must make the builds more stable before releasing them.

[Build 14316](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/) includes the bash now.

[image]

> **Run native Bash on Ubuntu on Windows**: In this build, you can natively run Bash in Windows as announced last week at Build 2016. To
>   do this, you first need to **turn on Developer Mode** via **Settings >
>   Update & security > For developers**. Then search for “Windows Features”
>   and choose “Turn Windows features on or off” and enable Windows
>   Subsystem for Linux (Beta). To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt
>   and type “bash”.